# Ошибка 403 репозитория Git

Tags: git, github

Git не дает разрешения залить файлы на новый репозиторий.

```
 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/appname.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Ввожу:

`git remote -v`: выдает все правильно:

```
origin  https://github.com/username/appname.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/appname.git (push)
```

Но если пытаюсь сделать: `git push origin master`, выдает вышеописанную `ошибку 403` с правами доступа. Возможно дело в том что при первоначальной настройке я поставил одни `git config --global user` и  `git config --global user.email`, а залить пытаюсь на аккаунт созданный на другом пк. На другом пк тоже стоит `git` и там я прописывал другие `git config`.

Если проблема в этом, то подскажите пожалуйста, как сменить первоначальные настройки пользователя, если не в этом, то в чем?

Comment: сертификат генерировали на новом компьютере ? или перенесли с предыдущего? Для начала проверьте это - `ssh -T git@github.com` - запускайте в консоли. Если увидите правильное имя в ответе -  с сертификатами ок.

Comment: сертифекат не переносил.

Comment: в консоли ввел :  "ssh" не является внутренней или внешней командой.

Comment: если в виндовой консоли - то это ожидаемо. Сертификат нужно либо сгенерировать ещё один (это хороший вариант), либо перенести с той другой машины. Но я присмотрелся - у Вас там используется https origin -  а в этом случае сертификат не сильно поможет.  Вообще в этом случае гит должен спросить имя-пароль. Как именно Вы работаете с гитом?  с консоли? с чудо-гуёвых приблуд?

Comment: да у меня windows.. с гитом работаю через Git Bash консоль.

Comment: просто когда я через браузер зашел на гитхаб, ввел логин-пароль то решил что этого достаточно. создал репозиторий а когда попробовал загрузить на него файлы чероз https получил ошибку 403

Comment: в целом, при git push/pull у Вас должны спросить имя-пароль. Может его закешировало... https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache

Comment: сейчас ввел git log и оказалось что я сижу под старой учетной записью. те пытаюсь залить коммит в другой аккаут на гитхабе. вроде через браузер зашел в новый акк но сам Git об этом не знает. может из за этого ?

Comment: ещё раз, имя-пароль в консоли спрашивает или нет?

Comment: нет. в виндовой консоли даже команды такой нет " - ssh -T git@github.com "

Comment: Просто попробуй те сделать pull в консоли

Comment: как это сделать? "pull" это команда ?

Comment: Да, `git pull`.

Comment: fatal : Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: логично - Вы находитесь не в репозитории.

Comment: я в принципе понял проблему и описал её в другом вопросе. дело в том что я нахожусь в одной учетке гита (git congig --list выдал : пользователь1) но пытаюсь закинуть в пользователя2

Answer (score -2):

Мне помогла команда
`git rebase origin/master`
а потом уже 
`git push origin master`

Comment: Как вам это помогло? Дайте более развёрнутый ответ.