# Как выйти из учетной записи в git console и доступ к оболочке

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

Решил вернуться к изучению git и появилась проблема с авторизацией.
Ранее на пк был установлен git, пытался его удалить, но он при пуше так же не показывает браузер с возможностью авторизоваться из возвращает ошибку.
Пытаюсь создать новый репозиторий по дефолтной подсказке от gitgub:

```
echo "# NameProject" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/User_Name/NameProject.git
git push -u origin main
```

Команда:

```
$ git push -u origin main
```

Выдает:

> remote: Repository not found.

> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/UserName/projectName.git/' not found

Пытался воспользоваться решениями из этой проблемы:"[Ошибка 403 репозитория Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651534/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-403-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-git)", но не помогло.

Команды:

```
git remote -v отрабатывает верно
sh -T git@github.co
git config --list --show-origin
```

Отрабатывают верно, аномалий не замечал.

Команда:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout = 10'
```

Должна в теории сбросить данные для входа, но так же не работает.

Собственно два вопроса как вызвать окно авторизации, если git pull и git remote add origin не работают как еще можно вызвать окно авторизации?

Использовал команду:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/User_Name/NameProject.git
```

Она не выдает ошибок, используя команду: git push -u origin main

Получаю в ответ:

> error: src refspec main does not match any
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/User/Project'

Comment: в этой команде `git remote add origin https://github.com/User_Name/NameProject.git` Вы не можете указать произвольный репозиторий. Для начала зайдите в свой гитхаб аккаунт и найдите там либо созданный Вами  репозиторий (он желательно должен быть пустым), или создайте новый. А потом нужно будет удалить старый origin  и добавить созданный.

Comment: git remote показывает что есть две удаленные репы fetch и push, что из этого удалить?

Comment: Удаляйте обе. Одна запись на push, вторая на pull ( если точнее, то на fetch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил поискать ответ на Ваш вопрос на просторах Интернета.
Чтобы авторизоваться в собственном аккаунте в GitBash, попробуйте ввести следующее:

```
git config --global user.email адрес
```

Пример:

```
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Надеюсь, что хоть как-то помог.